# Adding external swisstopo map into angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add swisstopo map in my angular 8 app. I'm new with angular and i really don't know how to includes this simple exemple in my component:

https://api3.geo.admin.ch/api/quickstart.html

I've tried to add the script link into my index.html and it is loaded but after that i don't know how and where to add the small plain javascript code to work with.

Put in the angular-cli.json the scripts javascript name. i don't know what i have to do to execute this script when the component is loaded

MapViewComponent.ts

```
`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';`

 @Component({
    selector: 'app-map-view',
    templateUrl: './map-view.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./map-view.component.scss']
 })
 export class MapViewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

 }
```

MapViewComponent.html

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Quickstart exemple from geo.admin

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <style>
  .map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
  }
 </style>
<title>GeoAdmin API example</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>My first GeoAdmin map</h2>
   <script src="http://api3.geo.admin.ch/loader.js?lang=en&version=4.4.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <div id="map" class="map"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var layer = ga.layer.create('ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe');
      var map = new ga.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [layer],
        view: new ol.View({
          resolution: 500,
          center: [2670000, 1160000]
        })
      });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expected to have the map loaded when i create a new MapComponent

Comment: Link does not work.

Comment: i'm in switzerland maybe it's because of the country, you cannot access to this to ? https://map.geo.admin.ch https://api3.geo.admin.ch/

Comment: Maybe I can help if you can write the javascript code you're trying to add.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i've adding the code from the website

Answer (score 0):

Alright, my original answer was trash.  [this is a much better (if older) example](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/)